# ARM asm "unrecognized instruction mnemonic" for ALIGN directive

Tags: assembly, arm, clang

I'm using Android NDK clang and compiling a mix of C and ARM ASM code. My ASM code sets up page tables:

```
cpu0_l1_ttbl:
         ALIGN 4096                                                                                                                                                                
         // 0x00_0000_0000--0x00_3FFF_FFFF (1GB)
         // -> L2 Table #0
         0x0000080000
```

I'm doing this because I'm told (by ARM) that page table locations should be 4KB aligned. However, when trying to compile, clang gives me this error:

```
ptable.S:86:9: error: unrecognized instruction mnemonic
        ALIGN 4096
        ^
```

I must not be groq'ing ARM ASM as I thought this was proper assembly?

Comment: Clang uses GAS directives / syntax, not ARMASM.  You want `.balign 4096`.  https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Balign.html .  (Or `.p2align 12`)

Comment: Or on arm `.align 12` is fine.  The main point is to use a `.` dot.  Also, you want to align the  label, so your align should go before that, if you want to go beyond compiling to functional.

Comment: "Assembly" is not a single language.  Every assembler has its own syntax for directives.  It is fortunate for us that some of them have chosen to be mostly compatible with each other, but it isn't something that you can assume without actually checking the manual for the specific assembler you are using.